# Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles

Tags: dokku, dokku-alt

I'm trying a first deploy for a dokku application.
I'm getting

```
   Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
   but only one can be used to install dependencies. Installing
   dependencies using the wrong package manager can result in missing
   packages or subtle bugs in production.

   - To use npm to install your application's dependencies please delete
   the yarn.lock file.

   $ git rm yarn.lock

   - To use yarn to install your application's dependences please delete
   the package-lock.json file.

   $ git rm package-lock.json
```

I had initially created by project with yarn, but there was also a package-lock.json file. Perhaps I used npm one time. I don't remember.

I followed the instructions and `git rm package-lock.json` and tried again.

- Same error

I then tried removing node_modules and reinstalling with `yarn`

- Same error

So, I did `git rm yarn.lock`, removed node_modules and installed with `npm install`.

- Same error

I then tried to

```
repo:purge-cache <app> 
repo:gc <app>
```

and tried again. You guessed it

- Same error

Any suggestions? I'm under pressure to deploy something and I'm stuck here.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually commit the changes removing the files? This is an error caused by the contents of your repository, not by Dokku.